# Why can't NetBeans 8.1 resolve std identifier?

Tags: c++, netbeans, std, identifier

Can somebody help me with the problem when NetBeans can't find my std? I tried to reparse the project and the directory solution doesn't work properly. I'm currently using 8.1 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, I needed to include `<stdio.h>`.